# Can I make a long fish array easier to read and maintain?

Tags: arrays, readability, fish, maintainability

I am writing a simple script in fish. I need to pass in an array as follows:

```
set PACKAGES nginx supervisor rabbitmq-server
apt install $PACKAGES
```

But as the array gets longer it gets harder to read and maintain...

```
set PACKAGES nginx supervisor rabbitmq-server libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev python3-dev virtualenv
```

Is there another way to define an array that is easier to read? For example, vertically with comments:

```
set PACKAGES
    nginx
    supervisor
    rabbitmq-server

    # LDAP packages
    libsasl2-dev
    libldap2-dev
    libssl-dev

    # Python packages
    python3-dev
    virtualenv
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can escape the newline to continue the current command on the next line (and lines with comments are ignored)
- You can use multiple `set` invocations

e.g.

```
set PACKAGES \
      nginx supervisor rabbitmq-server \
      # Python packages
      python3-dev virtualenv

 # LDAP
 set PACKAGES $PACKAGES libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
```

In current fish git, `set` has gained "--append"/"-a" and "--prepend"/"-p" options so you don't need to repeat the variable name (the "$PACKAGES" above).